# What does "head on back" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrasal-verbs

In a movie "Moana", there's this conversation between Moana and her gramma Tala:

> **Moana:** It's time to put my stone on the mountain.
>
> **Tala:** Okay! Well, then head on back! Put that stone up there.

Here, what does "head on back" mean?

I guess "head" here means "go". Then, can you say "go on back" instead of "head on back" here?

### EDIT

For more context, here's a [clip](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E9J7-7wU8CI) starting with the conversation above.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumptions are correct - [head](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/head) can be treated as a verb, meaning to move in a specified direction. For example.

> - After we got to the beach, we **headed** south.
> - After work, we all **headed** to the pub.
> - It's getting late, I think I'll **head** home.

... and to *head on* in this context simply means to continue on.

From that, we get **head on back**. Although it seems counterintuitive (and it is), *head on back* has become an idiomatic expression meaning to turn around and go back the way you came, or to some previous waypoint on your route.

> - After the hike, I **headed back** home.
> - I **headed back** down the river as the sun began to set.
> - You should **head back** home before the sun sets.

*Go on back* could also be used in your example:

> Well, then **go on back!** Put that stone up there.

It seems equally counterintuitive, but is also commonly used in this context.

Comment: Thanks. But shouldn't it be "come on back" instead of "go on back" in the original context? Because Moana is approaching to Tala, the speaker.

Comment: *come* and *go* are very much dependent on relative positions of the speakers. I'm presuming to a certain degree here, but it sounds like Moana and Tala have both progressed past the mountain, engaged in conversation, and Tala is instructing her to *go on back*. If Tala for some reason, was still standing on the mountain, shouting down to Moana, she would say *come on back*.

Comment: For more context, I've edited the question to add a clip showing the conversation in question. Please take a look at it and let me know if you think which is better, "go on back" or "come on back".

Comment: The clip shows that Tala and Moana are together on a beach, looking back toward the mountain. So as @mike said, "go on back" would be the appropriate alternative to "head on back." Tala would have said "come on back" if Moana were on the beach and Tala were herself on the mountain (or Tala were nearer to the mountain than Moana was)--in that case, Tala would be telling Moana to move nearer to ("to come" toward) Moana's position.

Comment: @Shosht In the context of the clip, by "then head on back", Tala tells Moana first to go up the mountain to put the stone up there and then to come back to the beach. Once Moana puts the stone on the mountain, she'll return to Tala, the speaker, which means that Tala has to say "come back" instead of "go back". No?

Comment: @JK2, no, I think you are misunderstanding what Tala is saying. The context of the conversation tells us that either Moana has already been at the mountain (or back in the direction of the mountain) by herself, or both Moana and Tala have. Tala is telling Moana to "return to the mountain" ("go back where you already were"). That's what "head on back" or "go back" means in this context.

Comment: @Shosht I don't get it. "It's time to put my stone on the mountain" means that Moana has yet to go up the mountain and put her stone up there. What in the context tells you that either Moana or both of them have already been at the mountain??

Comment: @JK2, the very fact that Tala says "then head on back" indicates that Moana (or both of them) have already come from the mountain or from a place between the mountain and where they now are.